# Can't Read phone number from content Provider query

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, activityresultcontracts

I used start activity with intent for select contact and receive data from `onActivityResult` method. `onActivityResult` method is deprecated and have to use `registerForActivityResult` solution.

Before:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK).apply {
            type = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_TYPE
        }
startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER)

if (requestCode == SELECT_PHONE_NUMBER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Get the URI and query the content provider for the phone number
        val contactUri = data!!.data

        val projection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
        val cursor = context?.contentResolver?.query(
            contactUri ?: Uri.EMPTY, projection,
            null, null, null
        );

        // If the cursor returned is valid, get the phone number
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val numberIndex =
                cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)
            var number = cursor.getString(numberIndex) // ->> this is phone Number String
        }

        cursor?.close()
    }
```

When I use

```
registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.PickContact())
```

I can't access phone number, can't query on DataProvider with

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
```

or

```
ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER
```

I get an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column data1

or (when using CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column number

(when using PhoneLookup.NUMBER)